# How to display some CSS content for div[data-attr="false"]:first-ot-type?

Tags: css, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Is is possible to display "HEADER FOR **OLD** DATA" only for the very first row of OLD data and not repeating it for each (in the same way blue border is not repeated)?

Considering (1) has been solved, is it possible (via `content:"..."`?) to display "no new data" if `shadow` `div` contains only `<div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>` (see example 2)?

```css
.shadow {
  margin-bottom: 50px
}

div[data-is-new='false'] {
  color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.57);
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

div[data-is-new='false']::before {
  display: block;
  content: "HEADER FOR **OLD** DATA";
  color: black;
}

div[data-is-new='false']~div[data-is-new='false'] {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Example 1</p>
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="header">HEADER FOR *NEW* DATA</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
</div>

<p>Example 2</p>
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="header">HEADER FOR *NEW* DATA</div>
  <span>No new data display via CSS with "content"?</span>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure will always be new data then old data you can try like below:

```css
.shadow {
  margin-bottom: 50px
}
div[data-is-new='false'] {
  color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.57);
}
div:nth-child(1 of [data-is-new='false']) {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

/* select only the first one */
div:nth-child(1 of [data-is-new='false'])::before {
  display: block;
  content: "HEADER FOR **OLD** DATA";
  color: black;
}
/* if no new data, show content after the header element */
.shadow:not(:has([data-is-new='true'])) .header::after {
  content:"No new data display";
  display: block;
}
/* for better support use the below 
   if the second child is old then you don't have new (considering the order will always be new then old)
div:[data-is-new='false']:nth-child(2)::before {
  content:"No new data display";
  display: block;
} */
```

```html
<p>Example 1</p>
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="header">HEADER FOR *NEW* DATA</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="true">new data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
</div>

<p>Example 2</p>
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="header">HEADER FOR *NEW* DATA</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
  <div data-is-new="false">OLD data</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We really need a `:first-of-attr` selector...

Comment: Also note that this solution uses `:has()` which is not fully available in all browsers yet. It's still behind a config flag in Firefox.

Comment: @TylerH that's why I am providing another solution which requires the html structure to be known

Comment: @TylerH and actually we have a first-of-attr selector. Updated the answer

Comment: Ah, IMHO it would be better to give alternate solutions in separate fiddles. Commented out code sections don't have the best visibility...

Comment: Well, we have `:not(div[attr] ~ div[attr])` but that's not quite the same thing... although I haven't seen then `nth-child(1 of [attr])` syntax before; nice!

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! A small problem however. Because div .header is a `flex` (row direction), then "No new data display" appears as a child of this flex and thus "in row" (whereas I'd like to have it below. How to bypass this problem?

Comment: @charnould You did not have any flex styles in your code. Can you edit your question to include a [mcve]? That will help prevent Temani and others from providing answers that fail to meet _unspecified_ criteria you may have.